# "во сто крат" vs "во сто раз"

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения

> ненавидеть что-нибудь **во сто крат** сильнее
>
> {vs}: ненавидеть что-нибудь **во сто раз** сильнее

I wanted to use "во сто крат" to hyperbolically express the idea of "гораздо + comparative", but I wonder if it is considered to be an outdated expression. Is it more common nowadays to use the genitive plural "раз"?

Comment: also it can be pronounced with the stress shifted back onto the preposition - ***вОстакрат***, which imparts it a sophisticated feel

Comment: ***в сто раз*** can be phrased as ***в сотню раз*** as well

Comment: "Во сто крат" is not used colloquially anymore, but it's perfectly fine to use it to produce a theatrical effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **во сто крат** is bookish while **в сто раз** is universal (note: **в**, not **во**). If you want to go really hyperbolic, you may as well use **в тысячу / миллион раз**. Or **сто миллионов**... you get the idea. :)

Comment: I'm curious: Why say "**во** сто крат"  and "**в** сто раз", even though they are both followed by "ст"?

Comment: I think that's because of the desired emphasis on the first element **во** in the set expression, which is more about emotion than simple count. Therefore, it's a full syllable.

Comment: The confirmation: it's the _stress_ on **во** indeed. https://phraseology.academic.ru/5763/%D0%92%D0%BE_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82 Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.

Comment: @Alone-zee - "Bo" in "во сто крат" is used because it's archaic/bookish, "в" in "в сто раз" is used because it's modern Russian.

Comment: @Yellow Sky Can you refer to a dictionary where the phrase _во сто крат_ is marked as 'archaic'? I've only seen it marked as 'colloquial' or 'bookish', depending on particular source.

Comment: @Alex_ander can you show other phrases using "во сто" or "(numeral) крат" ? Those are obviously archaic forms. And "colloquial" here I think is exactly that: archaic forms, that dropped out of general use, but survived inside few fixed idioms. This idioms is its full fixed form are not archaic perhaps, but the specific parts it consists of definitely are.

Comment: another example: http://ya.ru and search for "во чисто поле" - this "во" (despite next sound is not syllable) clearly stems from archaic language forms, that somewhat survived in folklore songs. But not in casual language.

Comment: @Arioch Of course, I can:  ... иное [семя] упало на добрую землю и принесло плод: одно во сто крат, а другое в шестьдесят, иное же в тридцать (Gospel acc. to St. Mathew ). Surely, you are right that **literal** usage or disassembling (which I didn't suggest) of this quite a contemporary idiom (I called it a _set phrase_ in my comment about the **stress** in it) would be archaic.

Comment: @Alex_ander then re-read what Yellow Sky wrote and what you opposed to. He was saying that "во" part is archaic, not the whole set phrase. Though technically he was not correct for another reason: "во" is still not archaic when the next sound is "в" again (во второй раз vs в первый раз)

Comment: Consequently, I believe that the stress/emphasis on the first syllable in "во сто крат" is not actually "desired" by speaker but merely is a by-product, it is yet another archaic form that got "frozen" inside this set phrase.

Comment: i think it's worthwhile to distinguish between ***во*** as a preposition of the Accusative on the one hand and of the Locative on the other, because in Locative this form is still quite contemporary: *во рту, во дворе, во лбу, во рву* etc., it's obvious from these examples that additional vowel is added to space out the conglomeration of consonants whereas archaic ***во*** in Accusative wasn't necessarily governed by the need to simplify pronunciation, modern ***во*** in Accusative however pursues exactly this purpose as well like in *во двор*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка interesting to note is all your "off the fingertips" examples "во рту, во дворе, во лбу, во рву" have one-syllable root with "o" being the root vowel.

Comment: @Arioch - No "o" in the root: "во всяком [случае]".

Comment: @YellowSky w.r.t. root "o" here I referred specifically to Баян's "Locative" examples and only them, I even quoted them explicitly. Your example is "в after в" case, like above in my "во второй раз" example. Here root does not matter, the "conglomeration of consonants" kicks in first.

Answer (score 1):

There are cases where they're not interchangeable.

You can say `стократно` but you can't say `сторазно`. Also you can say `многократно`, but you can't say `многоразно`. There's a word `многоразовый`, which is not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Вó сто крат** is **not** considered *outdated*. Some dictionaries mark it as *colloquial* and some other - as *bookish*. It's an idiomatic **set phase** (meaning *immeasurably*), as opposed to **в сто раз** which is most often used as a literal expression and is also colloquially used for an *exaggeration* (usually, about countable things: **зарабатывать я там буду *в сто раз больше***).

Speaking of *outdated* things, **literal** usage of **во сто крат** (where **крат** directly replaces **раз** and refers to *numbers*) can only be found in very old literature like Russian versions of Gospel:

> ... иное [семя] упало на добрую землю и принесло плод: одно *во сто*
>   крат, а другое *в шестьдесят*, иное же *в тридцать*.

As for your examples, the first one may sound too sophisticated for everyday speech while is OK in a letter, an article, etc. The second one ( with **в сто раз**) is a bit *informal/colloquial/spontaneous* and not suitable for something written, when applied to something that can't be expressed in numbers; **гораздо** or **намного** would sound better, applied to smth. like comparative '*amount of hatred*'.

Answer (score 0):

In daily life we usually use “**в сотню раз**”, “**в сто раз**” and “**во сто раз**”.

I’ve never heard anyone use “*в/во сто крат*”, but I saw it in books.

I don’t know what Sergey meant by “not во”, but I often hear people say the three versions I’ve suggested.